# Generating metamodel classes using maven and eclipse (JPA,Maven,Eclipse)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, maven, m2e

I'm using m2e (1.0.100), Eclipse (Indigo SR1) and hibernate-jpamodelgen (1.1.1.Final).
I want to have hibernate generate the **Canonical** metamodel from my entities when I compile the projects.
I was able to do this previously when I was working on a non-maven project and I followed the numerous tutorials there are on how to configure the eclipse project to use this jar.
However, to the best of my understanding, when using m2e it is best (mandatory?) to let it do the eclipse configuration for you and so I'm not sure how this should be done.
This [hibernate tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/jpamodelgen/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e265) explains how to use the generator with maven and eclipse but separately.
I think what I'm missing is gluing my pom, which was generated as a simple no archetype pom, and my eclipse project configuration so that they enable me to do some JPA magic.
BTW, following the above tutorial for maven caused my maven-generated jars to contain the _ classes but these are not seen by eclipse since they are only in the jars and not in the actual projects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Java 1.5?  This is not helpful, but at my previous client we looked into doing JPA2 with Maven + Eclipse and decided that the metamodel generation in Java 1.5 was more trouble than it was worth.  We decided to stick with native Hibernate until our deployment environment was migrated to Java 1.6.

Comment: btw when I say "more trouble than it was worth", I mean we couldn't figure out how to do it... otherwise I'd tell you.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer Thanks, We're using 1.6 and I was able to make some headway with the m2e mailing list referring me to an open bug and a workaround. I hope to try the workaround today or tomorrow and post a complete answer to my question

Comment: Good luck, and I know some people that would be interested in the answer if you find it.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer Just answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the same question on the m2e-users mailing list and got the following answer ([link](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg01964.html) for those wanting the full thread):

Basically one should manually configure (for example using the above mentioned hibernate tutorial) eclipse to use the generator and configure the same directory maven uses (for me it was target/generated-sources/annotations) as the output directory.

According to the committers of m2e, the project currently does not change these eclipse files and so this won't be overriden from them.

The problem I did face was that this information is lost (and so the manual change is needed again) when using GIT and switching between branches as I don't want to commit any eclipse related files to the SCM.
Currently this is an acceptable solution and I hope m2e will be able to add this missing feature.

**Update**
The information that is lost, at least according to my experience, is the definition of the `target/generated-sources/annotations` folder as a source folder. Just as an FYI.